# NetBeans: Javascript Code Completion doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, macos, netbeans

I've just started using NetBeans (PHP version 7.2 for Mac) and love it so far.  One thing that I haven't been able to figure out is how to get Code Completion to work for Javascript files in the same fashion as it does for PHP, CSS and HTML files.  For example, if I type "fun" in a PHP file, it'll pop up a box that allows me to choose "function":

[image]

If I do the same thing in a Javascript file, I get nada:

[image]

I've looked all over the place and I have not found a way to add this functionality.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this example, try the *Source-> Complete Code* command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default).

In any case, the JavaScript editor is [currently being rewritten](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/new_javascript_editor_in_the) from scratch so better code intelligence is to be expected in the near future.

**Edit:** I almost forget the most obvious answer... Make sure your file belongs to a loaded project. Code intelligence doesn't work properly outside projects.

Comment: Thanks Álvaro.  I did see this method but it seems clunky compared with the PHP code completion.  I have to admit that I got totally spoiled by XCode when working on a couple of iOS projects recently.  NetBeans is making a great start toward that for me -- and it's head-and-shoulders above what I was using before (skEdit).